# Suppressing methods from ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

`ngResource` looks like a really handy way to manage data access in a RESTful (or at least REST inspired) Api... but some of the data I want to manage using it is read-only (at least from my application's perspective).

Is there any way to prevent the objects returned by `ngResource` from adding the save, remove and delete methods?  As far as the documentation is concerned it looks like an only additive api...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to to remove the instance methods from the Constructor prototype:

<kbd>**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/U76FWzrr0r6HbZw5Ht0L?p=preview)**</kbd>

```
app.factory('SomeResource', function($resource){

  var r = $resource('/some/api/path');

  delete r.prototype.$save;
  delete r.prototype.$delete;
  delete r.prototype.$remove;

  return r;

});
```

Comment: I should have thought of that!  Thanks so much.

Comment: Don't forget to _also_ `delete` the non-prefixed methods on the constructor as per @kornfride below, e.g. `delete r.save; delete r.prototype.$save`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
  var Car = $resource('/cars');
  var myCar = new Car();
  myCar.color = 'red';
  myCar.$save();
```

Do:

```
  var Car = $resource('/cars');
  var myCar = {};
  myCar.color = 'red';
  Car.save(myCar);
```

And:

```
  var Car = $resource('/cars/:id');
  var myCar = Car.query({id: 52});
```

Then you won't ever have to see those `$`-methods/properties.

Comment: On second read, I think I misunderstood what you meant. What you want is for there *not* to be any methods like `Car.save` `Car.delete` etc. I don't know how, but I would very much like to replace the default methods myself. I'm looking into it as well now...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that possible since the source code looks like this:

```
 var DEFAULT_ACTIONS = {
    'get': {method: 'GET'},
    'save': {method: 'POST'},
    'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
    'remove': {method: 'DELETE'},
    'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
  };
```

and:

```
    actions = extend({}, DEFAULT_ACTIONS, actions);

    function extractParams(data, actionParams) {
      var ids = {};
      actionParams = extend({}, paramDefaults, actionParams);
      forEach(actionParams, function(value, key) {
        if (isFunction(value)) {
          value = value();
        }
        ids[key] = value && value.charAt && value.charAt(0) == '@' ?
          lookupDottedPath(data, value.substr(1)) : value;
      });
      return ids;
    }

    function defaultResponseInterceptor(response) {
      return response.resource;
    }

    function Resource(value) {
      shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this);
    }

    forEach(actions, function(action, name) {
    ...
```

Would be nice addition to angular to let us modify the `DEFAULT_ACTIONS` in the future. Meanwhile you can quickfix it by...

```
  var myResource = $resource('/myresource');
  delete myResource.save;
  delete myResource.delete;
  delete myResource.remove;
  delete myResource.query;
```

... I guess; although that's kinda "dirty".

Comment: No need to have two answers. Just update/edit your first answer.